# BEM structure feedback

Tags: html, css, bem

I'm not sure if SO is the right place to ask such question. Let me know if it is not so.

I'm learning the BEM CSS methodology recently and I like how it solves many of the CSS problems like specificity issues. It makes our CSS more maintainable.

As I'm new to it, I'm having a hard time creating correct HTML layout with proper [BEM](https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/) class. I've created a module using BEM and would like experts on opinion on what could be the correct layout according to the best practices of [BEM](https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/).

Here is the screenshot of what I'm trying to using [BEM](https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/) CSS methodology.

[image]

Here is HTML layout that I've come up with so far, please let meknow what would be right way to achieve the same.

```html
<section class="content">
  <div class="step-nav">
    <div class="step-item">
      <div class="step-item__left">
        <div class="step-item__progress">
          <div>
            <i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span>Step 1</span>
          </div>
          <div>100%</div>
        </div>
        <h2 class="step-item__title">General Information</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="step-item__right">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true">
                <span class="screen-reader-text">Next</span>
              </i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="step-item"></div>
    <div class="step-item"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks about correct, but you should have just a `step-nav` block, and all the subsequent child components are simply elements, i.e.:

- `step-item` should really be `step-nav__item`, since `item` is an element of `step-nav`
- `step-item__left` should really be `step-nav__item--left` since `left` is a modifier. With that in mind, you should combine them so that you will be using `<div class="step-nav__item step-nav__item--left">` in the same nesting level, removing that extra unnecessary level of `<div>` nesting

Of course, if you think `step-nav` is too long of a word, you can use `step` instead.

Comment: Thanks. But what about the inner of `step-item__progress` tags.